# Is it possible to get the Norton AntiVirus status on PC using Java?

Tags: java, norton

Is it possible to get the Norton AntiVirus status on PC using Java? For example last updated date, current status like active or inactive, upcoming update date and etc. Is it possible through java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer most likely to fit your question is: No.

The more sophisticated answer is: Maybe - with a lot of effort.

Let me explain this: There is not direct way of accessing the AntiVirus status using any kind of Java API, so that's why the quick answer is not. However, you can use Java - like any other language - to load the contents of files on the filesystem (or check their existence). So if you can determine the status by looking up any kind of file related information from the system the answer might be yes.

But anyway - I don't see for what you would need that information.

Comment: In my company decided to maintain the PC status. Thats why its required. Is it possible with any other language?

Comment: I doubt it. If there were an easy possibility any virus could simply check "is antivirus software installed?" and if the answer is yes simple perform some kind of "hidden" action. I'd try contacting Norton and ask them how to integrate that logic.

Answer (score -2):

Try following steps:

1. Go to login.norton.com and sign in.
2. Create an account and complete a registration process.
3. Begin and enter a new product key. (Your product key is the 25 characters that are stored on the CD that you bought at a retail store or online)
4. Click on accept and install